# How can I access the files uploaded in the file manager and display them in a page of xwiki using velocity

Tags: xwiki

*Hello, I am working with Xwiki and faced a problem*

**How can I access the files uploaded in the file manager and display them in a page of xwiki using velocity. After displaying the files in the page I have to open the files by clicking the eye button (appear when imported using Open Office).**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

{{fileManager.recentFiles/}}

Use this code to retrieve the list of all files uploaded via file manager in xwiki..I am also unable to customise the view part....